# PHP datetime from string with dayname

Tags: php, datetime

i'm trying to parse a webpage into a data structure, therefore i need to convert two strings (one date, one time) into a datetime object.

sounds easy, but my problem is the format.

example date is: '*Donnerstag 23.10. 2014*'
example time is: '*20:30*'

to match this into *ONE* datetime i need to concat them 
so my resulting

NOTE: solution edited inline (correct, vs wrong, which was my question)
dateTimeString is '*Donnerstag 23.10. 2014 20:30*'

```
$date = "Donnerstag 23.10. 2014";
$date = explode(" ", $date);
$time = "20:30";
$datetimeString = $date[1].$date[2]." ".$time;

// wrong
$datetime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->createFromFormat("d.m.Y H:i");

// correct
DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y H:i");
echo $datetime->format("d.m.Y H:i");
```

i expected the output to be '*Donnerstag 23.10. 2014 20:30 -> 23.10.2014 20:30*'
but the resulting output is the day/time i run the script... so the createFromFormat failed, without errors/Warnings though!

note: i also tried cutting off the weekday, but still got the same problem, the datetime gets not parsed correct. do i really need to break it down to every single bit (day, month, year and then assign it??)

Comment: Well you never use your `$datetimeString` in the process afterwards so obviously it couldn't work...

Comment: I think you need to get rid of the word Donnerstag, there is no benefit in having it, and I have been unsuccessful trying to get PHP to recognise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
$date = "23.10.2014";
$time = "20:30";
$datetimeString = $date." ".$time;
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y H:i", $datetimeString);
echo $datetime->format("d.m.Y H:i");
```

Comment: the problem was my call for createFromFormat, your example showed me that i have to call it static DateTime::createFromFormat instead of creating an instance and calling the method. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check below -

```
$date = "Donnerstag 23.10. 2014";
$date = explode(" ",$date);
$time = "20:30";

$new_date =date("d.m.Y H:i", strtotime($date[1].$date[2].$time));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your $datetimeString from strtotime() function. It will create a long number. Try this.

```
$date = "23.10.2014";
$time = "20:30";
$datetimeString = $date." ".$time;
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y H:i",strtotime($datetimeString));
echo $datetime->format("d.m.Y H:i");
```